# PostgreSQL: связать поля таблицы

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть две таблицы. В первой есть колонка с информацией о штрафном времени в секундах (использую тип integer). Во второй есть колонка с информацией о денежном штрафе. Денежный штраф рассчитывается по схеме: (штрафное время) * (штраф за минуту штрафного времени).
Как установить такую связь между таблицами и сделать автоматически вычисляемое поле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, таблица с "штрафным временем" называется Times, а таблица с величиной штрафа - Pays. Можно сделать следующим образом :

- создать триггерную функцию, которая будет высчитывать штраф по переданной ей строке, содержащей "штрафное время":

```
CREATE FUNCTION calc() RETURNS trigger AS  
$BODY$  
  BEGIN  
   IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN  
    --тут рассчитываем и добавляем в таблицу Pays "денежный штраф" 
   ELSIF(TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
    --тут рассчитываем и обновляем поле "денежный штраф" в таблице Pays
   END IF;   
  END;  
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- создать триггер для таблицы Times, который при каждом добавлении строки в таблицу Times будет дергать триггерную функцию и дополнять таблицу Pays:

```
CREATE TRIGGER calc_tr
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Times
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc();
```

Возможно, в дальнейшем вам понадобится и одновременно почистить зависимые строки в данных таблицах, это так же делается внутри триггерной функции, посмотрите примеры работы с ними [тут](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-trigger).